# Manual Object serialisation

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class of the following type, which I want to serialise.

```
class HighTrafficPojo{
    private List<SomeObjets> objectList;

class SomeObject {
    Map<ObjectTypes,Double> someData
    ...
enum ObjectTypes {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    ...
```

Since the serialised object is in a high traffic node of my app, I need to make it as small as possible. Since Im not very familiar with java serialisation my first thought was to do it myself. for example, to serialise a HighTrafficPojo I would do:

- insert objectList.size() as int.
- for each object in objectList do:

  - insert object Map size
  - for each key,value pair in the map:
  - insert the key as char and the value as double

And de-seriallize by going backwards and instantiate the HighTrafficPojo from the data. Before I start on doing such a tedious work, Is there something ready out there that can give me the cheapest serialisation possible? Im not sure ja

Comment: Why serialisation and not a DB ?

Comment: Define 'high traffic'. I suggest you try standard Serialization and see if you really have a problem. It's easy enough.

Comment: And if you really do have that problem, use Protocol Buffers.

Comment: Can you please add links for your suggestions so I can be able to see if it is relevant for me? The High traffic object will be delivered between machines in a scale of milliards a month. I need it signature as low as possible.